# Qual è il significato di "cavallino" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Voleva bene al ruvido spilungone dinoccolato, **cavallino** e bitorzoluto come una *masca*, che aveva la mania dell'Inghilterra e di Cromwell e faceva il procuratore di una ditta vinicola.

La frase fa riferimento a Beppe Fenoglio (il soggetto di "voleva bene" è Calvino). Non capisco bene cosa vuol dire "cavallino" in questo brano. Nei dizionari ho trovato che si tratta di un aggettivo che significa "del o dal cavallo". Il senso nella frase è che Fenoglio assomigliava in certo modo a un cavallo?

Comment: È sicuramente l'aggettivo che hai trovato sul dizionario, quindi la tua spiegazione è decisamente plausibile; forse fa riferimento al viso del personaggio?

Comment: Un esempio di viso "cavallino" è quello dell'attore Fernandel https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxMzQ2Nzk2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjE3NTYwMjE@._V1_UX214_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ecco una [fotografia di Beppe Fenoglio](http://www.centrostudibeppefenoglio.it/images/home/beppe-fenoglio-04.jpg): guardandola mi sembra molto plausibile che la frase del libro si riferisca all'aspetto del viso come tu hai detto.

Comment: Personalmente avrei avuto più problemi con “masca”... Sarà [questa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/masca2/)?

Comment: @DaG:  Quando ho letto il brano, ho cercato "masca" nel Treccani e ho subito pensato che fosse quello che hai messo nel tuo link: nel libro c'è scritto in corsivo e il dizionario afferma che si tratta di una voce regionale del Piemonte.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti scrivere quello che hai detto come risposta?

Comment: ho cercato di riunire le risposte dei vari commenti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È sicuramente l'aggettivo che hai trovato sul dizionario, quindi la spiegazione è decisamente plausibile; guardando la [Fotografia di Beppe Fenoglio](http://www.centrostudibeppefenoglio.it/images/home/beppe-fenoglio-04.jpg) l'aggettivo "cavallino" si adatta al volto dell'autore.

Un altro esempio di viso cavallino è quello dell'attore [Fernandel](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxMzQ2Nzk2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjE3NTYwMjE@._V1_UX214_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg).

Il sostantivo "*masca*" è invece una voce dialettale per "*strega*" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/masca2).

A mio avviso l'amore di Calvino (ma anche di Ferrero) per Fenoglio traspaiono da una descrizione così schietta dello scrittore.